# Powershell SharePoint 2016 csom 403 forbidden error

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, csom

So new to CSOM and wanting to know if I am coding something wrong or where I need to look to resolve this issue. Or even if there is a SharePoint 2016 security setting that needs to be enabled for CSOM to work.

Also note, authentication is via Claims Authentication on the site it doesn't work on.

Thanks!

## code

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
$SharePointSite = 'https://Sharepointsite/sites/sitename'
$SharePointGroup = 'Test Group'
$Creds = Get-Credential
$SPContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("$SharePointSite")  
$SPContext.Credentials = $Creds
$SPGroups=$SPContext.Web.SiteGroups 
$SPContext.Load($spGroups)         
$SPGroups=$SPGroups.GetByName("$SharePointGroup")
$SPContext.Load($SPGroups)        
$SPContext.ExecuteQuery() 
$SPGroups.Title
```

On my test side which is http://sharepointsite/site/testsite it works fine and finds the group.

On the root of the test site, https://sharepointsite/ it works and returns no group found.

On another site under the same root http://sharepointsite/sites/othersite it fails with "Access denied" but I don't have access to that site.

When I test to an https://sharepointsite2 or https://sharepointsite2/site/testsite I get "403 Forbidden" But I have full access to sharepointsite2 root, sites, and central admin.

Comment: You might need to enter the Claims based username in the Get-Credential because if you enter the Windows "domain/username' it will treat you as an unauthorized user and give 403 error . If you enter your Claims user name like ClaimsID|username and password which is same you will start getting outputs.

Comment: Get-Credential wont take the format for Claims but I tried doing "New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$UserName",$Password)" and that didn't work.

Comment: Okay , let me know one thing . You have claims based authentication right ? On which zone do you have Claims based ? What is the authentication on the Default Zone ?

Comment: I can't answer that because that is managed by another team and I do not have that info or access to it. I was informed the script must be CSOM and auth was Claims and a list of SP sites. That is all I am working with unfortunately.

Comment: I found some info and was able to add "e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders.Remove("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED");
              e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");" 
into my script and now getting 401 or access denied depending on how I format my credentials. Below is the url but guess my 403 issue has been resolved.
http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/accessing-mixed-mode-sharepoint-web-applications-with-csom-and-powershell/